# lambda output in C++

Tags: c++, lambda, c++14

The output of the following code is `0, 0`. What is the problem with the code? `m` is passed by reference, it should be `1`, right?

```
int main()
{
    int m = 0;
    int n = 0;
    [&, n]() {m = n + 1; };
    cout << m << endl << n << endl;
}
```

Comment: You did not invoke the lambda. It's just as if you declared a function without actually calling it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to invoke the lambda

```
[&, n]() {m = n + 1; }();
//                    ^^
```

Now the output should be what you expect.

---

As Piotr's comment says, you can also initialize a variable to hold the lambda and invoke that

```
auto lambda = [&, n]() {m = n + 1; };
lambda();
```

Comment: A more classic approach would be to first store the lambda somewhere, so that the OP doesn't get the impression that putting parens right after the lambda is the only correct syntax.